# I got an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" while trying to render the filter functionality on my todo list on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the following line of code while trying to render the filter functionality on my todo list on React

````
.filter(FILTER_MAP[filter])
.map((task)=> (
  <Todo
    id={task.id}
    name={task.name}
    completed={task.completed}
    key={task.id}
    toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
    deleteTask={deleteTask}
    editTask={editTask}
  />
));```
````

Answer (score 0):

just something wrong in key={task.id} and try to change

```
key={task.key}
```

Comment: still giving an error:         Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)